# Multi-file gather using selectable file channels

Tags: java, nio

I implemented a multi-file gatherer input stream which is able to read and combine data from previously scattered file segments. However, the current version uses RandomAccessFile along with fixed size ExecutorService, and with lots of CPU overhead. I'd like to avoid these I/O threads and perform a single threaded Selector based approach. Unfortunately, FileChannel (or JDK7's Path.newByteChannel()) is not selectable. Is there a way to do this data-gather in an NIO way?

Comment: Could you try and narrow down the cause of the CPU overhead first?

Comment: Unfortunately not. VisualVM does not work on my Win7 (throws NPE somewhere deep)

Comment: Can't you just cycle through your file channels round robin and use blocking reads?

Comment: I do blocking read() on each RAF in threads, then join the results. I hoped there is a non-blocking way of doing it - similarly to ServerSocketChannel and SocketChannel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at jdk7's AsynchronousFileChannel.

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer but why does it have to be Selectable? It has scattering reads and gathering writes, and files are always ready for reading and writing. So why Selectable?